# Dapper: String is passed on as Text when invoking postgres functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, mapping, dapper

When calling a DB function in Postgres, the type for `String` changes to `text` and that of `DateTime` to `timestamp`. Is there any way to ensure this doesn't happen?

Setup:
a DB function:

```
foo(v_from character varying, v_to character varying, v_date date)
```

Dapper code:

```
public static decimal GetValue(DateTime vdate, string cur) {
        string sql = @"SELECT _public.foo(@vFrom, @vTo, @vDate)";
        var data = connection.QueryFirstOrDefault<decimal>(
                                             sql,
                                             new
                                             {
                                                 vFrom = cur,
                                                 vTo = cur,
                                                 vDate = valdate,
                                             }
                                            );
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
Npgsql.PostgresException : 42883: Function _public.foo(text, text, timestamp without time zone) does not exist
```

Somehow string is converted to text instead of character varchar. Similar story for DateTime to timestamp.

Tried the variation with DynamicParameters.Add(), but still the same result.

Comment: try implicit cast: `SELECT _public.foo(@vFrom::character varying, @vTo::character varying, @vDate::date)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this?

```
public static decimal GetValue(DateTime vdate, string cur) {
        string sql = @"SELECT _public.foo(@vFrom::character varying, @vTo::character varying, @vDate::date)";
        var data = connection.QueryFirstOrDefault<decimal>(
                                             sql,
                                             new
                                             {
                                                 vFrom = cur,
                                                 vTo = cur,
                                                 vDate = valdate,
                                             }
                                            );
}
```

Comment: Perfect! That works...I guess there's no way around specifying these type as part of the sql?

Comment: Don't know - I'm a db guy, not java